# Specification for weights & bias in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am working with Tensorflow & trying to build a deep network model. I will use ReLU activation with SGD/Adam optimizer (minimization of cross-entropy) & L2 regularizer (penalize large weights to over-fit).

My dataset has 115599 rows with 13 columns, from which 1:12 columns are actually input (X) & 13th column is the binary response. I have standardized the input X.

For weights & bias, we are supposed to take sample from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean & variance 1. Previously when I am doing it with MNIST dataset, we are setting the weights & biases at zero with `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))` & `b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))` as the response had 10 **different levels** (0-9).

My question is, how can I specify the weights for a binary response which has only **two** different levels. Should I put b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))?

The code I tried so far placed below;

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import pandas as pd

df_X=pd.read_csv('/home/prm/use_validation.csv',usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],skiprows=[0],header=None)
df_scale = (df_X - df_X.min()) / (df_X.max() - df_X.min())
d = df_scale.values
Response = pd.read_csv('/home/prm/use_validation.csv',usecols = [12],skiprows=[0],header=None)
labels = Response.values
data_use = numpy.float32(d)
labels = numpy.array(Response,'str')

#tensorflow
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(115599, 12))
x = data_use
w = tf.random_normal([100,115599],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random_normal([100,2],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32) ##[NOT SURE, PLEASE ASSIST]##

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(w,x)+b)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The shapes in your model do not match up. Keep in mind that if you have tensors `A` and `B` with shapes

```
shape(A) = [a1, a2]
shape(B) = [b1, b2]
```

then to perform

```
C = tf.matmul(A, B)
```

you MUST have `b1 = a2`, and the resulting tensor `C` has shape

```
shape(C) = [a1, b2]
```

In your example, `A` corresponds to `x` which has shape `[115599, 12]`, and `B` corresponds to `w`, which you want to determine the shape, and `C` corresponds to `y`, which must have the same shape of the target, which is `[115599, 1]`.

You obtain that `w` must have shape `[12, 1]`, while `b` must have rank 1 and the same shape as the second shape of `w`, so `b` must have shape `[1,]`.

Comment: `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([12, 1]))
 b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

 y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)`

will it suffice? Please confirm

Comment: This is not working & I am getting multiple errors. Can you please provide the slice of codes for two lines in case of weights & bias?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out;

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import pandas as pd

df_X=pd.read_csv('/home/prm/use_validation.csv',usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],skiprows=[0],header=None)
df_scale = (df_X - df_X.min()) / (df_X.max() - df_X.min())
d = df_scale.values
l = pd.read_csv('/home/prm/use_validation.csv',usecols = [12],skiprows=[0],header=None)
labels = l.values
data_use = numpy.float32(d)
labels = numpy.array(l,'str')
#print data, labels

#tensorflow
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(115599, 12))
x.shape
# x = data_use
w = tf.random_normal([12,1],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
w.shape

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,w)+b)
```

This is working fine for me!